# Bash at job not running - Array

Tags: arrays, bash, batch-processing

I have built a bash script that runs fine when executed from the command line but does not work when run as batch job (with at). First I thought because of the environment but when debugging I think there is a problem with arrays I need to create. When run from command line log is created and its content is what I expected but when run with at any log is created. Any idea for what is causing this issue?

A short script with the piece of code I suppose it is not running is below

```
#!/bin/bash

fsol=`date +%Y%m%d`

for dia
  in 0 1 2 
do

  var=$(date -d "$fsol +$dia days" +'%Y-%m-%d')

  orto=`awk -v j=$var 'BEGIN { FS=","} $2 == j { print $3}' hora-sol.dat`

  h_orto=${orto:0:2}
  m_orto=${orto:2:2}

  a_orto+=($h_orto $m_orto)

echo "dia $dia" $var $h_orto $m_orto  >> log1.txt

done

echo ${a_orto[@]} >> log2.txt
```

Data in hora-sol.dat

```
32,2016-02-01,0711,1216,1722,10.1885659530428
33,2016-02-02,0710,1216,1723,10.2235441870822
34,2016-02-03,0709,1216,1724,10.2589836910036
35,2016-02-04,0708,1216,1725,10.2948670333624
36,2016-02-05,0707,1216,1727,10.3311771153741
37,2016-02-06,0706,1217,1728,10.3678971831004
38,2016-02-07,0705,1217,1729,10.4050108377139
39,2016-02-08,0704,1217,1730,10.4425020444393
40,2016-02-09,0703,1217,1731,10.4803551390436
41,2016-02-10,0701,1217,1733,10.5185548339287
42,2016-02-11,0700,1217,1734,10.5570862213108
43,2016-02-12,0659,1217,1735,10.5959347763989
44,2016-02-13,0658,1217,1736,10.6350863580571
45,2016-02-14,0657,1217,1737,10.6745272092687
46,2016-02-15,0655,1217,1738,10.7142439549499
47,2016-02-16,0654,1217,1740,10.7542236006922
48,2016-02-17,0653,1217,1741,10.7944535282585
49,2016-02-18,0652,1216,1742,10.8349214920733
50,2016-02-19,0650,1216,1743,10.8756156133281
51,2016-02-20,0649,1216,1744,10.9165243743526
52,2016-02-21,0648,1216,1745,10.9576366115941
53,2016-02-22,0646,1216,1746,10.9989415078031
54,2016-02-23,0645,1216,1747,11.0404285846154
55,2016-02-24,0644,1216,1749,11.0820876932144
56,2016-02-25,0642,1216,1750,11.123909005324
57,2016-02-26,0641,1215,1751,11.1658830035395
58,2016-02-27,0639,1215,1752,11.2080004711946
59,2016-02-28,0638,1215,1753,11.2502524821626
60,2016-02-29,0636,1215,1754,11.2926303895977
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a smaller more isolated script? [mcve]

Comment: How are you calling `at`? It is likely your shebang is being ignored and `sh` is attempting to run your script.

Comment: I run `at -f ./prova.bash -t 02121427`. When problems solved I plan to add to crontab jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running manually, it generated:

```
# cat log.txt 
dia 0 2016-02-12 0659 1217 1735
dia 1 2016-02-13 0658 1217 1736
dia 2 2016-02-14 0657 1217 1737
06
59
06
58
06
57
```

Scheduling with at:

```
# echo "/tmp/horasol/script.sh" | at now +1 minute 
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 1 at Fri Feb 12 12:11:00 2016
```

It generated exactly the same:

```
# cat log.txt 
dia 0 2016-02-12 0659 1217 1735
dia 1 2016-02-13 0658 1217 1736
dia 2 2016-02-14 0657 1217 1737
06
59
06
58
06
57
```

Note that warninig informing that 'at' uses /bin/sh:
**warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh**

Tell us how you conclude that "*does not work when run as batch job (with at)*"

Tell us more about your "*when debugging*" moment.

Perhaps I'm reproducing here using a different proccess as you. And due to this difference it works for me.

Comment: Hi @hudson-santos This code is a part of a bigger script, when trying to find when the main script failed I come to this piece of code. "Does not work" means that the bigger script does not execute subsequent commands and the short example does not create any log.

Comment: Is it a problem that the script starts with `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: No, cause I've schedulet it and executed with #!/bin/bash normally. Perhaps you have a permission issue. Have you checked if those log.txt can be generated for example in /tmp/log.txt? Try just >> /tmp/log1.txt and the same to log2.txt.. This /tmp is a drwxrwxrwt directory. :) This means everyone can write your own files there. If permission is the problem, using /tmp/ you're going to discover.

Comment: Tell us more about "there is a problem with arrays I need to create". Any error messages? Post here everything you judge not confidential for your company..

Comment: This is an assumption I make, no error messages. It is the point where I think the script stops.

Comment: Can not save to `/tmp`. Running in an Ubuntu machine. I have no permission problem with other scripts run in the same machine.

Comment: Understood, try to use a runtime.log to output things as it happens in real time. For example after assigning var= you put echo "at this moment, var is $var" >> runtime.log

after assigning orto= you can echo "at this moment, var orto is $orto" >> runtime.log

..and do on. This is a pretty fine debugging technique.

sh -x your_script.sh is also another debugging method you could try.

Comment: Hi @hudson-santos the script does not run if launched with `at -f ./prova.bash -t 02121427` but runs fine if `echo "./prova.bash" | at now +1 minute` what's the difference? environemnt?

Comment: Following your advice and this post [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work) I could succeed and now the job is running with crontab